# Change custom domain login screen footer text © 2016 salesforce.com to © 2016 <my company>.com

Tags: login, custom-domain, mydomain

I Have custom domain registered on my salesforce org and i have configured login page branding (customized logo and right frame URL) and that change the logo for multiple screens like forgot password, create new password etc. which is really good.

one thing that is blocking to me is the footer text that showing saleforce instead of `myCompanyname`. is there any way to change the footer text for all these screens.